# how to set HttpOnly and Secure flag set in apache2.4.6 and tomcat

Tags: apache, security, httponly

I have an apache2.4.6 and dotcms2.3.2 in suselinux. I want to set httponly and secure falg in dotcms and tomcat . I set  these configurations in apache and tomcat: 
`<Context useHttpOnly="true">` in `context.xml`
`<Connector maxThreads="400" connectionTimeout="3000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" secure="true" />`  in `server.xml`

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly
```

or

```
Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
```

in `httpd.conf`.

after that restart tomcat and test with burp suite , but it does't set in cookie .

Comment: Salam:-D  `Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly`  should work unless **mod_headers** is not installed! or header doesn't exist!

Answer (score -4):

```
Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
```

in **`httpd.conf`** works.

Comment: It overwrites session cookies.